# How to access the sails app with AWS EC2 Public IP

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sails.js

I have a sails webapp deployed in Aws EC2 Ubuntu instance. When I lift the sails in production mode(sails lift --prod --verbose) I can access my app by typing ip with port number (xx.xx.xxx.xx:1337). When i am trying to access it with Ec2 Public IP(xx.xx.xxx.xx). It is showing "This Webpage is not available".
Is it possible to access the app from Public IP??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the Issue by editing my iptables to:

-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

Open 443 port i.e. HTTPS

-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEP